# Preserve whitespaces when echoing linux commandline output

Tags: php, html

when we type nslookup command on linux:

```
[root@vmcentos ~]# nslookup 8.8.8.8
```

the answer will be formatted like this:

```
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa    name = google-public-dns-a.google.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
8.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns1.level3.net.
8.in-addr.arpa  nameserver = ns2.level3.net.
ns1.level3.net  internet address = 209.244.0.1
ns2.level3.net  internet address = 209.244.0.2
```

but when trying this in apache:

```
<?php
$var1 = `nslookup 8.8.8.8`;
echo $var1;
?>
```

or even:

```
 <?php
    $var1 = `nslookup 8.8.8.8`;
    print$var1;
 ?>
```

In the Browser the page shown like this:

> Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 Non-authoritative answer: 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa name = google-public-dns-a.google.com. Authoritative answers can be found from: 8.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns2.level3.net. 8.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns1.level3.net. ns1.level3.net internet address = 209.244.0.1 ns2.level3.net internet address = 209.244.0.2

so How to print the output of the command in the browser like the output in Linux console?
(I want it the same format with the blank lines and newline (\n) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most straight-forward approach would be to surround the output with `<pre>` tags, so that the browser will render the text exactly as it is in the sourcecode of the page:

```
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', $var1);
```

Another solution could be to use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br), which would at least preserve the line-breaks, but multiple spaces and tabs are still rendered differently by the browser.

Comment: Thanks but it printed them with center alignment, how to solve this problem ( I want left alignment). @Till Helge

Comment: This is just basic HTML. `<pre>` doesn't have centered alignment by default. That has to be your doing. Instead of using `<pre>` you can also use any other element and use CSS to set `white-space: pre` on it.